# Is there anyway to select and save any part of array?

Tags: python, file, select

ı want to select anypart of my list and save while programming

so ı m looking for a command like f.save[i:j] ;

```
f = open ("text.txt","w")
f.write("123456789")  **thats nine bit and ı wanna selec between second and fifth bit ** 
a = f.save[2:5]
```

something like that

Comment: Do you mean save to disk? You should use the pickle module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html), which serializes the array (and other Python objects) and saves it to a file. It also loads the file and deserializes the contents, giving off a dictionary. Read the docs. You can also use one of it's implementations, i.e. [shelve](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html) or [persistent dict](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576642/), which also supports json and other formats instead of `pickle`.

You can also use a database like sqlite or just a plain text file and use your own implementation.

`I tried but pickle does not working for me`

What is not working? Please give more thought to your question. Try using shelve:

```
>>> import shelve
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> db = shelve.open('/path/to/my/database/file.db', writeback=True) # Notice the file must already exist
>>> db['a'] = a[2:5]
>>> db.close()
>>> quit()
# New interpreter is opened
>>> import shelve
>>> db = shelve.open('/path/to/my/database/file.db', writeback=True)
>>> db['a']
[3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: what if a[] is a random string ? any problem?

a= [random.uniform(10,100)for in i range(1000)

Comment: No. `a` can be any python object supported by `pickle`. Read the docs linked in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pickle
f = open("text.txt","w")
pickle.dump("123456789"[2:5], f)
f.close()
```